# Include home page template in specific category template

Tags: categories, templates

I have a specific category who's page I'd like to look like the home page of my site, with all the nice sliding featured stories, etc. If I create a file `category-slug.php`, can I do some sort of include of the index template?

If it helps, I'm using wootheme's FlashNews theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat ghetto but fast way to do this is to just use `get_template_part`, for example,

```
get_template_part('index');
```

A better use for it is to grab "parts" of your template and not a whole index, but it still works.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work. I'm not familiar with the theme you reference, but in most if you copy over index.php and rename it category-slug.php you'd have an excellent starting place. You may have to adjust some of the queries for featured sliders etc.

Comment: Is there a way to actually include the index.php template, rather than copy and paste?

Comment: I suppose you could create a blank category-slug.php page and then use include('index.php'); to reference the index file, though I've never tried it.